# set up integration test for file upload functionality with uppy in nextjs

Tags: testing, next.js13, vitest, uppy

I'm trying to test an image upload functionality with vitest. The functionality is working as it's supposed when I test manually. There is two elements to the component. A form and Uppy Dashboard. Once the form is submitted, there is a guard clause that checks if the image is uploaded. If that is true then the form data is added to the uppy instance as meta data and the Image is uploaded. After that the Image is presented using FileReader.

here is the test

```js
it('uploads an image', async () => {
    /* test upload functionality */

    /* set up variables */
    const { container } = render(<Dashboard />);
    const uploadInput = container.querySelector('input[type=file]') as HTMLInputElement;
    const submitButton = container.querySelector('button[type=submit]') as HTMLButtonElement;

    //assert upload input and submit button are in the document
    expect(uploadInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(submitButton).toBeInTheDocument();

    //assert submit button and upload input are of type submit and file respectively
    expect(uploadInput.type).toBe('file');
    expect(submitButton.type).toBe('submit');

    /* upload image */
    await waitFor( () => {
      fireEvent.change(uploadInput, { 
        target: { files: [new File(['(⌐□_□)'], 'test.png', { type: 'image/png' })] }
      });
      expect(uploadInput.files).toHaveLength(1);
    });

    /* submit form with image */
    await waitFor( () => {
      submitButton.click();
    });

    //assert image to be in the document
    const image = container.querySelector('img');
    expect(image).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

The last assertion is failing. The image variable is for some reason null.
I have tried wrapping it in a waitFor and it's still null.

---

**UPDATE**

I've set up unit tests for the form and learned that it was never being submitted and it seems, this is the real issue here. So far I have tried using user-event to click the submit button in that unit test, calling the buttons click method and using fireEvent to fire a click event. I'm still trying different methods hence the lack of code here. Atleast now that I know where the problem lies, I think it'll be much easier to find the solution. I have also set up a test for default values and updated the codebase so that the radio buttons have them. This is working splendidly and that test is passing. Lastly I've updated the code above so it matches the current implementation of the integration test.

Comment: You are getting null because the <Dashboard/> component doesn't have <Image/> component or <img/> tag present.

Comment: Try to log that container you're querying the img tag on the console.

Comment: It's showing that the container hasn't updated which is the problem. There is no img tag but it's supposed be 2. Once the file is uploaded the form and uppy is supposed unmount and the images mounted and this is triggered by the form submission i.e ```submitButton.click()``` but this is not happening which is my confussion. I have checked so that the colorize and enhance radio buttons are checked and they are. The image is also added to uppy.

Comment: So, wait for the image to appear in the container. Once the mounted img is available, the img will be ready to query.

Comment: I get a timeout error when I expect the image to appear inside the last waitFor I have also tried increasing the timeout limit with no avail. Is there another way I can wait for it?

Comment: Query img tag into the waitFor block and force it to not return `null`.  After that, the image variable isn't going to show null, it should have a value. I have questions, can you explain why you put fireEvent in a waitFor block and gave `async` to the callback as well as all the callbacks functions, do you have anything inside the block that does asynchronous stuff?

Comment: I was using userEvent earlier. kind of forgott to remove ```async```. Thank you for the reminder though! xD I tried asserting ```container.querySelector('img')```not to be null and it's timing out. Increased the time limit further. same thing.

Comment: Could there be an issue with the libraries? I did succeed two days ago and then I cleaned the code before I committed but then it broke. Tried to revert back and solve since with no success. Maybe the issue is beyond the code? ***Thank you very much btw, appreciate you taking the time***

Comment: Which library you're talking to? Alright, remove all the waitFor fn. Make it synchronous. I think all the tests will pass except the img tag or it'll be available. Did you try it?

Comment: If I remove the waitFor on the file upload ```fireEvent.change``` Then the file never gets uploaded and the input stays empty. I have updated the quastion because I learned the problem is with the form submission. All the assertions are passing and were all along, it's just that the image was never coming into view and it makes sense now that I know the form was never being submitted. I'm using vitest and jsdom and was thinking maybe there is a problem there but now I'm researching form submission in jsdom environment and perhaps I just need to read some more on that xD

Comment: I understand that the first uppy instance is created and uppy renders a dashboard. Then you upload an image and uppy mount this image to an img tag. This is it to test Am I right? Normally, If I don't do it with uppy and build an upload component myself I would test this the same. Initially, the img tag wouldn't be available in the document. So, the step I would follow that `fireEvent.click("upload___button" getting from DOM query)` Then I put the image variable and condition into the waitFor block because it has to wait for the submit button to be clicked.